# Выделить совпадения в тексте

Tags: c#, uwp, текст

### Описание

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь сделать пользовательский поиск в тексте, то есть чтобы совпадения выделились жирным шрифтом. Поиск я уже делал и всё хорошо работает:

```cs
private void FilterRefresh(string text, string pattern)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
    {
        TextBlock_Output.Text = Regex.Replace(text, $"{pattern}", $"[{pattern}]");
        //Тут совпадения отмечаются вот так: [Это] совпадение, а это - нет.
    }
    else
    {
        TextBlock_Output.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Только вот как сделать совпадения жирными с помощью C# а не XAML я не знаю. Нашёл решение проблемы для Windows Forms, для Xamarin, но только не для UWP.

---

### Вопрос

Как можно решить эту проблему в UWP?

---

С UWP работаю первый день, прошу строго не судить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прокопался в документациях, а так же часть взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20819810/12903672), ну и собственно получаем такое решение:

### Код

```cs
private void TextBox_Search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pattern = TextBox_Search.Text;
    RefreshFilter(text, pattern);
}
```

```cs
private void RefreshFilter(string text, string pattern)
{
    string openSymbol = "[";
    string closeSymbol = "]";

    TextBlock_Output.Inlines.Clear();
    string taggedText = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, $"{openSymbol}{pattern}{closeSymbol}");
    string[] parts = taggedText.Split(new[] { openSymbol, closeSymbol }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    bool insideTag = false;
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        Run run = new Run
        {
            Text = part,
        };

        if (insideTag)
        {
            run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        }
        else
        {
            run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        }

        TextBlock_Output.Inlines.Add(run);
        insideTag = !insideTag;
    }
}
```

### Результат

[image]